# Arrows in overflow-x

Tags: html, css

How can i show some arrow in my nav-items in mobile view with `overflow-x`? If the scroll bar is in the left side it should show some arrow pointing to the right side. Same as the right side view. I'm still currently learning with CSS.

Here is my current CSS code:

```css
ul.nav.header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.nav-tabs {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.viewrifyimage {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

.servicebtn,
.contactbtn,
.careerbtn,
.aboutbtn {
  font-family: cairo;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.nav-item {
  background-color: black !important;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.nav-item:hover,
.nav-item:focus {
  background-color: #39ac49 !important;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.boder {
  background-color: grey !important;
  color: black;
}

.active:focus {
  background-color: #39ac49 !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.nav-link {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
}

.nav-link:focus,
.nav-link:hover {
  color: white;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link,
.nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #39ac49 !important;
  border-color: transparent !important;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<ul class="nav nav-tabs header">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text aboutbtn active" aria-current="page" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#about"><i class="fas fa-users"></i> About Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text servicebtn" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#secu"><img class="logotab" src="{{ asset('img/a.png') }}"> security printing</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text servicebtn" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#it"><img class="logotab" src="{{ asset('img/b.png') }}"> I.T Solutions</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text servicebtn" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#service"><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Viewrify®</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text contactbtn" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#contact"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i> Contact Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link text careerbtn" data-bs-toggle="tab" href="#career"><i class="fas fa-sticky-note"></i></i> Careers</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image: Picture of nav-items]

Comment: Please remove the `laravel-8` tag as this is not relevant to the code you are showing.